# Extract residuals from adonis function in vegan package

Tags: r, multivariate-testing, vegan

I am using the adonis function in the vegan package to determine effects of different environmental factors in forest plant community composition in different regions. I would like to first use adonis to remove the region effect, this is, to fit a model like

```
adonis_region<- adonis(community ~ region,permutations=999,method="bray")
```

Where community is a presence/absence data matrix of species in forest patches belonging to different regions.

Then I would like to use the residuals  of this model as the response variable for some other analyses. I know I could use strata to model region as a block variable, but this does not interest me, as afterwards I want to perform another kind of analysis  where I would like the region effect to be removed.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get residual values from the adonis model.

Any hint of some other kind of multivariate analysis that could solve this problem is very welcome.

Comment: Cross posted at r-sig-ecology mailing list: http://r-sig-ecology.471788.n2.nabble.com/Extract-residuals-from-adonis-function-in-vegan-package-td7578737.html

Comment: ...and there are a dozen or so responses (36 in French) in r-sig-ecology.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics.